# How to get log-likelihood from squared deviance in Scikit Learn

Tags: mathematical-statistics, scikit-learn, likelihood, bic, information-criteria

The score() function computes D^2, the percentage of deviance explained, but I'd like to get the log-likelihood to calculate BIC. What's the formula to go from deviance to log-likelihood?

Score function reference:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.GammaRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.GammaRegressor.score

Comment: There is no method to get the devaince.  Sklearn focuses more on prediction that inferential stats so it lacks a lot of the functionality you would find in say R's `glm`.  Have you looked at statsmodels?

Comment: @DemetriPananos The link OP offered pretty much contradicts what you said

Comment: @DemetriPananos Statsmodels is awesome, and one of their devs hangs on this Stack (I think he has email alerts for the statsmodels tag, but whatever). I remember trying to do inference on a multinomial logistic regression in Python and having a difficult time pulling out the deviance until I started using Statsmodels instead of SKLearn. It might be possible in SKL, but SM made it way easier.

Comment: @Firebug Oh, that is a new development.  Hadn't caught up with that update.

Comment: @Dave yes, I know one of the devs hangs out here.  I think I've angered them once before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deviance, refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359997/60613), which I'll quote below:

> $$\begin{matrix} \text{Null Deviance} \quad \quad \text{ } \text{ } &
>   & \text{ } D_{TOT} = 2(\hat{\ell}_{S} - \hat{\ell}_0), \\[6pt]
>   \text{Explained Deviance} & & D_{REG} = 2(\hat{\ell}_{p} -
>   \hat{\ell}_0), \\[6pt] \text{Residual Deviance}^\dagger \text{ } & &
>   \text{ } D_{RES} = 2(\hat{\ell}_{S} - \hat{\ell}_{p}). \\[6pt]
>   \end{matrix}$$
> In these expressions the value $\hat{\ell}_S$ is the maximised log-likelihood under a saturated model (one parameter per data point), $\hat{\ell}_0$ is the maximised log-likelihood under a null model (intercept only), and $\hat{\ell}_{p}$ is the maximised log-likelihood under the model (intercept term and $p$ coefficients).

So, starting from Explained Deviance, $D_{REG}$:

$$D_{REG} = 2(\hat{\ell}_{p} -
  \hat{\ell}_0)$$

Therefore:

$$\hat{\ell}_{p}=\frac{D_{REG}}{2}+\hat{\ell}_0$$

You'll have to estimate $\hat{\ell}_0$ if you want to compute the exact value.
If you simply want to compare models, then that term is constant among them, and can be safely ignored.

---

<sub>Ben (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/173082/ben), Is R-squared truly an invalid metric for non-linear models?, URL (version: 2018-07-31): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359997</sub>